# How to authenticate VSCode extension via browser SSO so extension can post to server API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I want to create a simple VSCode extension that does a REST API POST of the contents of the editor window to a URL.

The issue is the URL is in a corporate environment behind a browser based single sign on sequence that requires multi-factor authentication with a hardware token and does multiple redirects when a user logs on normally through the browser. I'm not looking to circumvent this in any way, but simply authenticate the VSCode extension somehow so it can do the POST (and re-authenticating every session is fine, just not for every post).

The SSO authentication process seems to be fine with multiple windows in the browser, so e.g. you can login in one window and then do say AJAX POSTS from Javascript in another window to the REST API. So I kind of want VSCode to be considered just another window in that scenario.

I am thinking something like opening a browser window within VSCode itself to allow the user to manually authenticate, then somehow the session is maintained and VSCode can POST to the REST API URL when it wants?
Or perhaps triggering a window in an external browser for the authentication but then how would VSCode be authenticated to do the POSTS as the external browser would be a separate application.

Client OS is Windows 8 (corporate policy!) if that makes any difference. I don't have any access to modify anything on the server.

Any thoughts/suggestions welcome, thanks.